# add cancel button along with selected value to remove accidentally added value

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a multiple selected dropdown box and a button.If you select multiple values and click on button then it will display under it.My jQuery code is like this:

```
$('#example-inheritButton').multiselect({
    inheritClass: true
});

jQuery('#int_btn').click(function(){

    var myData = {};

    jQuery( ".tole_int option:selected" ).each(function(i,e) {

        myData[e.value] = e.innerHTML;

    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo site_url().'/interests-with-stars'; ?>",
        data:{myData: myData}
    }).done(function(data){
        jQuery('.int_div').html(data);
    });

});
```

Now, I want to add cancel button with the selected value to remove accidentally added value.So what code I have to write?

**Note:** I want to uncheck that value while click on cancel button not to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the buttons in PHP code like the following:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["myData"]))
{
    $array = $_POST["myData"];
    foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
        echo '<div>'.$array[$i].'<input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" id="'.$array[i].'"></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

You need to add this in your jQuery:

```
$(".delete").live("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $(".tole_int option[value='"+id+"']").prop("selected", false);
});
```

Comment: I mean i have to uncheck when click on cancel button, I dont want to delete that accidentally added value.

Comment: @Nisarg: I have edited the answer, please check if that is the desired code.